# Valid signature to delete copy/move assignment operator

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, assignment-operator

Is it valid to delete copy or move assignment operators (maybe exclusively) using the following signature (note the `void` as result type)?

```
struct A
{
    A() = default;
    void operator = (const A &) = delete;
    void operator = (A &) = delete;
    void operator = (A &&) = delete;
};
```

G++/clang++ accepts above code (practically it may be considered as shortening). Are there more strict requirements for signatures of assignment operators to make them explicitly deleted?

Is there any interference in case of inheritance?

Comment: If you have a user-declared copy constructor the compiler will not create a default move constructor. Pretty sure the same applies to assignment.

Comment: These are the key 5 methods [Rule of 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29465527/c-rule-of-5-copy-and-move-constructor-and-assignment-caveat-to-copy-or-move)

Comment: @user4581301 *maybe exclusively* here means, that any combination or even the only of mentioned operators may be present in actual implementation.

Comment: @GemTaylor Irrelevant here. The question is about signatures of operators, not about an idioms.

Comment: Interesting point. Diving into the standard. It should be covered in **[class.copy]**. Back if I find anything interesting.

Comment: [agh! Too slow] That link shows the correct signatures for the 4 copy operations you need to = delete if you want to disable copying. You can get away with not setting the return type, but it is not good practice, and at some point you may get a compiler warning.

Comment: Only hard requirement I'm seeing is [A user-declared copy assignment operator X::operator= is a non-static non-template member function of class X with exactly one parameter of type X, X&, const X&, volatile X& or const volatile X&.](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/class.copy#17). Absolutely nothing about the return type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [[class.copy.assign]](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy.assign#1.sentence-1):

> A user-declared *copy* assignment operator `X​::​operator=` is a non-static non-template member function of class `X` with exactly one parameter of type `X`, `X&`, `const X&`, `volatile X&` or `const volatile X&`.

and similarly for [move](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy.assign#3.sentence-1):

> A user-declared *move* assignment operator `X​::​operator=` is a non-static non-template member function of class `X` with exactly one parameter of type `X&&`, `const X&&`, `volatile X&&`, or `const volatile X&&`.

There is no restriction here on the return type. Only on the parameter type. The version of these that the compiler generates [returns `X&`](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy.assign#6), but that in no way obligates you to do the same thing.

If you're deleting the assignment operator anyway, returning `void` is fine. Note that you do not need to delete both the copy and move assignment operators. If you delete the copy assignment, the [move won't be implicitly generated](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy.assign#4.1).

> Is there any interference in case of inheritance?

No. The implicitly generated assignment operators would just be [defined as deleted](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy.assign#7.4) (and would return `X&`, although that's orthogonal). If you declare one, then that's of course up to you to do whatever you want.

Comment: IOW, return type `void` is even legal when you _define_ the functions instead of deleting them.

Answer (score 2):

It's perfectly valid. If your class does not need/want/cannot work with those functions then making that explicit and deleting them is the right thing to do (and even though return types don't participate in overload resolution you may want to get them correct just to reduce confusion).

Comment: I particularly interested in correcteness of the use of `void` as result type.

Comment: @Orient: I recall there's a quirk with making them private, but the `void` return type is definitely fine.

Comment: Return types don't participate in overload resolution.